# Ошибка при инициализации структуры через фигурные скобки

Tags: c++, c++11

При попытке инициализации структуры через фигурные скобки вылезает ошибка:

> error C2440: инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "initializer list" в "FunctionRelease"

```
struct FunctionRelease
{
    std::string firstOperand;
    std::string secondOperand;
    Operation operation;
    bool isTwoIdentifier = false;
};
```

...

```
int main()
{
    struct FunctionRelease functionRelease = { "v0", "v1",  Operation::DIV, true };
}
```

В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Уберите `= false` из определения структуры.

Comment: @alexolut: http://ideone.com/QO66ON (Или это особенности gcc?)

Comment: @VladD теперь попробуйте с C++11

Comment: @alexolut: А где можно попробовать? Ideone умеет только 14.

Comment: @alexolut помогло, спасибо.

Comment: @VladD http://melpon.org/wandbox/

Comment: @alexolut: Угу, спасибо! 14 глотает, 11 нет. Напишите ответом?

Comment: @VladD если найду причину :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Инициализация экземпляра класса путём последовательного перечисления в фигурных скобках через запятую значений для полей этого класса, называется агрегатной инициализацией. Легко догадаться, что для возможности агрегатной инициализации требуется чтобы сам класс удовлетворял требованиям агрегата.

Эти требования в последних стандартах звучат по-разному (выделение текста моё):

- C++11

  > An *aggregate* is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), **no *brace-or-equalinitializer*s for non-static data members (9.2),** no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11),
  > no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3)
- С++14

  > An *aggregate* is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no private or
  > protected non-static data members (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

Т.о. в более свежем стандарте ослабили требования к агрегатному типу, убрав необходимость отсутствия инициализации непосредственно в классе.

Т.к. проблема проявила себя, значит был использован вариант [c++11](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QN0Odi5pR3F1xgVJ). И для решения достаточно убрать инициализацию члена `isTwoIdentifier` в классе.
Но если есть возможность скомпилировать код в режиме [c++14](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/64wzPeZhhQlGa4bh), то никакие изменения вовсе не потребуются.