# Автоматическое присвоение значений параметров свойствам объекта

Tags: c++, конструктор, параметры

Для присвоения значений параметров одноименным свойствам я могу использовать список инициализации:

```
class A {
    A(int a, int b, int c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {};
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

Но если таких параметров будет, например, шесть, то строчить список инициализации как-то некрасиво. Существует ли более элегантный способ присвоения значений параметров конструктора одноименным свойствам объекта?

Comment: что значит более элегантный способ присвоения значений ??

Comment: Если они все типа int, то можно передавать массивом

Comment: Если объект должен быть инициализирован, то без конструктора не обойтись.

Answer (score 2):

Такой способ есть только для структур у которых:

1. Нету `private` или `protected` не статических членов
2. Нету пользовательских конструкторов
3. Нету `virtual`, `private` или    `protected` базовых классов
4. Нету виртуальных функций
5. Нету инициализаторов по-умолчанию

Если всего этого у вас в классе, структуре или объединеии нету, то можно писать так:

```
struct Foo{
    int i;
    double d;
    char c;
};

Foo foo = {42, 3.14, 'c'};
```

Это называется [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

В противном случае придется *строчить список инициализации* в конструкторе.

Comment: Нету такого слова `нету` :) Инициализаторы допускаются в [c++14](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/585037/176217)