# Как C++ выводит тип для шаблонов функций?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

На самом деле я не подразумеваю на свой вопрос полного и исчерпывающего ответа, иначе меня можно просто отправить на [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) читать это огромное чтиво. Когда-нибудь может и займусь этим, но в данный момент мой уровень английского не сильно позволяет это сделать. Но я хочу примерно представлять каким образом он решает выводить типы, а конкретно разберу мою проблему на примере:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> 
T** createarray(int n, int m) {
    T** mas = new T*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        mas[i] = new T[m];
    }
    return mas;
}

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    std::cin >>n >> m;
    double **arr = createarray(n, m);
}
```

Хочу создать двумерный массив, при этом чтобы элементы массива могли быть произвольного типа. Но код, не комплируется и оно в целом понятно, почему. Я пытаюсь вызывать функцию, в которой как бы не понятно, что такое тип `T`. Если бы например функция была такого вида:

```
T** createarray(int n, int m, T another_argument) {
    T** mas = new T*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        mas[i] = new T[m];
    }
    return mas;
}
```

То в целом становится более понятно, что надо сначала разобраться, что за тип нам передали и этого же типа будет функция. Но все же в контексте `double **arr = createarray(n, m)` ВРОДЕ КАК понятно, что функция тоже должна быть double? Однако тут встает другая проблема, я же могу вывести тип функции допустим как int, а потом кастануть к double? получается неоднозначность, что я могу привести к любому типу и потом просто кастануть неявно. Однако, что если я передам какую-то более сложную структуру данных по типу string? vector? Такой неоднозначности в целом уже не будет. Однако ошибки комплияции данная идея не устранила. Хотя в целом данные мысли не очень имеют место ввиду того, что я не совсем уверен как C++ действительно пытается выводить типы. Он по факту их выводит с помощью аргументов? Есть ли какой-то способ заставить мою функцию работать без явного указания типа: `double **arr = createarray<double>(n, m)`.

Comment: А вы гарантируете наличие контекста? :) Тогда создавайте `void createarray(T*** array, int n, int m) { ... *array = mas; }`. Ну не принято в С++ учитывать **в** функции то, что происходит **за** ее пределами...

Comment: @Harry это хорошо подмечено, однако почему бы тогда и не вбрасывать ошибку когда контекста нет? в данный ситуации он же есть (и вообще я планирую данной функции контекст давать всегда).  вообще в целом я уже подозреваю, что при выводе типов "внешний" контекст вообще не смотрится. тогда в целом я подозреваю, что заставить мою функцию работать не сильно то и можно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как вы уже заметили, на вывод аргументов не влияет то, как используется возвращаемое значение функции.

С единственным исключением - зашаблоненным `operator`ом преобразования:

```
template <typename T>
struct Helper
{
    int m, n;
    
    template <typename T>
    operator T **()
    {
        // Тут код создания массива.
    }
};

Helper CreateArray(int m, int n)
{
    return {m, n};
}
```

Тогда `double **arr = createarray(m, n);` заработает.

Comment: не совсем пойму, почему `{m, n}` заставляет вызвать `operator T **()`. Как это происходит? `{m, n}` это типа будет вызываться конструктор `initializer_list` который проинициализирует `m` и `n`? Но как тогда вызывается сам `operator T **()`?

Comment: @Learpcs `return {m, n};` примерно эквивалентно `Helper ret; ret.m = m; ret.n = n; return ret;`. Этот `operator T **` вызывается не внутри функции, а снаружи, когда вы пытаетесь присвоить объект `Helper` указателю.

Comment: @Learpcs это [агрегатная инициализация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/585037/176217).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ да уж, то что я загнул про `initializer_list` это чушь конечно.